# Single-Sign-On choices to use with Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, single-sign-on

What types of Single-Sign-On what can I use with Windows Phone?

Now, I'm using Facebook Single-Sign-On. But I don't know if I can use, for example, Windows Live ID, Google, Yahoo, etc.

I don't want to make users of my app register again. I need users registered, but I can use another ways to sign in in my app.

Answer (score 1):

OpenId for Windows Phone 7 - [SevenAuth](https://github.com/arktronic/sevenauth).  Here's a [demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HNOFNhT2sk).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code:

```
void checkGuid()
    {
      object uniqueID;
      DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueID);
      byte[] bID = (byte[])uniqueID;
      _clientID = Convert.ToBase64String(bID);
      Debug.WriteLine(_clientID);
    }
```

simply put your getting the unique hardware ID for each user that uses your app, now you simply send that to a WCF Service of some kind and store that string in a database, you can save information along with their Name, or their favourite style, its really quite simple when you think about it, but makes such a big difference in your app, ofcourse your app on start up would connect to your WCF Service and pull back the values (no need for hardware ID since that never changes) the beauty is your query string can just contain the Hardware ID of the Device and then match it with the Hardware ID on your database to get the values,

I am doing a similar thing right now, you can then link the HWID to their OpenID accounts

Comment: I liked the concept here...but for taking it one step forward want to use both HWID and credentials. For eg: I login through App1 and get a token from portal, after this App2 should not need credentials to proceed.
So is it possible that App1 can store the token somewhere and only App2 can access it, but no other apps.

Comment: talk to the same database, that way you can query the DB for the ClientID if they are registered voila it all works, now the only other thing you need to do is perhaps have one authentication model, something simple like give them a question to answer to which they know they answer to (provided at registration), that way you know it really is them

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Microsoft released the [Windows Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live) which reportly allows you to do this, but I haven't gotten it to work smoothly yet.