# Single Sign On on Multiple Apps Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

We are developing multiple apps for our client which all can be used using same credentials(credentials of there company portal).
So we want to implement something like single sign on, such that user need not to login each app.
I have already gone through  these links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826544.aspx

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598411/single-sign-on-choices-to-use-with-windows-phone-7

Here is what i need exactly:

step 1.) When user login to one app(say App1), the portal will return a token, ineed to store this token somewhere, such that only authorized apps can access this.
Step 2.) when any other app(of same group) launches it will check on the location for the token and if token exists, it will not demand for credentials.
Step.3) When user logs out from any app, it will remove the token from shared location.

We have already implemented this in IOS using keychain(possibly wrong term as i am not ios developer).This keychain provides a common space for the apps signed with same certificate.

As per my knowledge uptill windows phone 7.5 there is no possibility. Does windows Phone 8 has something for this.
If not i am open to any kind of suggestions to serve the purpose.

P.S. : Security is our major concern, So when you suggest please let us know you think there could be any security concers though hack or phone loss.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hey Mohit, I need to implement similar functionality in Windows Phone 8/8.1 but not finding any solution. As this thread is quite old now, did you have any success in this problem? Please suggest how you implemented this in your apps? Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks...!!!

Comment: Hi Prabh, As mentioned by Joe, this does not seems feasible.

Comment: Thanks Mohit for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to be corrected but this won't work.  Apps are isolated and can't share things like data packets and such.

Answer (score 0):

i am not a windows app guy.
but a trick can work.
**caution:**

following can raise security concerns if API token expiration time limit is not properly considered.

use firesharp / any XMPP service (suitable for windows client) to send api tokens to other devices like notification message.
handle the notification in such a way that token is not displayed.

and also remember, there is no such think as log out in API authorization.
you will have to restrict access with token expiration time limit.